# Regular expression to find the phone number pattern in plain text using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am having a plain text which contains phone numbers in different patterns. I need to find phone number pattern exists in the plain text.
I have done this

```
 $regex = '/^(?:1(?:[. -])?)?(?:\((?=\d{3}\)))?([2-9]\d{2})(?:(?<=\(\d{3})\))? ?(?:(?<=\d{3})[.-])?([2-9]\d{2})[. -]?(\d{4})(?: (?i:ext)\.? ?(\d{1,5}))?$/';
 $text = "fhsd hjkh ksd fsd fjkfhdsk 333-445-33333 sdfhjksdh s sdfjksd fdf";
 if(preg_match($regex,$text,$match)){
     print_r($match);
 }else echo "not found";
```

It detects the phone number only if we give the phone number as input. It is not detecting the phone number pattern in the plain text.

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can describe  the phone number formats you are trying to detect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `^` from the beginning and `$` from the end of the regular expression:

```
$regex = '/(?:1(?:[. -])?)?(?:\((?=\d{3}\)))?([2-9]\d{2})(?:(?<=\(\d{3})\))? ?(?:(?<=\d{3})[.-])?([2-9]\d{2})[. -]?(\d{4})(?: (?i:ext)\.? ?(\d{1,5}))?/';
```

You may read more about [anchors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php).

**UPDATE:** The regular expression for a hyphen-separated phone number in three parts should be this:

```
$regex = '/\\d+-\\d+-\\d+/';
```

Comment: after removing `^` and `$`, it worked fine for the above phone number, but, if i changed the phone number to `971-2-6772040`, it is not working. Please check this.

Comment: this doesnt matches with the phone numbers like 950 444 433322. what to do for this kind of phone numbers. Our regular expression should match all patterns of phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

use this expression for hyphen separated phone no.

$regex = '/\d+-\d+-\d+/';